# Are there specific grammar rules for naming variables?

Tags: variables, naming

I am creating an ontology for urban systems. For instance if we have the variable that indicate the size of the population I would name it (using the so called camel notation) `sizeOfPopulation`. The length of the street as `lengthOfStreet`. Is there a specific or standardized way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct answer to this question because it's extremely subjective.
[Programming Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style), [Coding Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions) and [Naming Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)).

You are probably familiar with: *[Tabs versus Spaces](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaces-what-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e)*?

TL;DR: Choose a style with your team or for youself, and be consistent. Look at strictly managed open source code for ideas, eg: Qt, ChibiOS, Linux.